# Could not locate element on pop up using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, popup

I have web application in which if select value from drop-down then pop up gets open . 
Now I want to access elements on that pop up using selenium Webdriver can you please help me  , I had tried `driver.switchTo().window(WindowHandle)`  , but it is not possible can you please  help me to make this ..

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("selector"))).selectByVisibleText("text");      
String handle1 = driver.getWindowHandle(); 
driver.switchTo().window(handle1);
```

Comment: driver.switchTo().window(WindowHandle) is not for popup. try to use focus the element or popup. you can try this new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).perform();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set<String> pops=Driver.getWindowHandles();
 Iterator<String> it =pops.iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    String popupHandle=it.next().toString();
   System.out.println("Driver Now switched to Pop Up with Title- "+ Driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle).getTitle());
   }
}
```

Comment: Its giving error of remove type argument for me for                     
    Iterator<String> it =pops.iterator();

Comment: Its giving error of remove type argument for me for                     
    Iterator<String> it =pops.iterator();

Comment: did you import java.util.Iterator; ?

Comment: can u try this.. Set<String> pops=driver.getWindowHandles();
         for (String p: pops) {
           System.out.println("Driver Now switched to Pop Up with Title- "+ driver.switchTo().window(p).getTitle());
         }

Comment: Error displaying : Unable to locate element which is on pop up.

Comment: So you are able to switch to the pop up rt? in that case can you post the html of pop up and the element ur tring to find

Answer (score 0):

please use the above Html code copied in another comment by me

public class PopupWindow

{

```
public WebDriver driver;
String parentWindow,childWindow;

@Before
public void setUp()

{
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("file:///C:/Users/vkiran/Desktop/select.html");


}

@Test
public void popupTest() 

{

    Select dropwdown=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='myURLs']")));
    dropwdown.selectByVisibleText("News");
    Set <String> handles =driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> it = handles.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        parentWindow=it.next();
        childWindow=it.next();

    }

    driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
    driver.close();//closing pop window
    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);//switch back to parent window
    driver.quit();//close current active window which is parent

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Pop URL on Select</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function openPop()
{

    var Sel_Ind = document.getElementById('myURLs').selectedIndex;
    var popUrl = document.getElementById('myURLs').options[Sel_Ind].value;
    winpops=window.open(popUrl,"","width=400,height=338,resizable,")
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="myURLs" onChange="javascript:openPop();">
<option value="">Select a page...</option>
<option value="http://www.bbc.co.uk">News</option>
<option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Music</option>
<option value="http://www.google.com">Laughs</option>
<option value="http://www.google.com">Search</option>
<option value="http://www.google.com">Help</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```